# Como faço para que um objeto se movimente na tela usando tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, jogos

Já comecei meu código só que não sei o que esta acontecendo de errado para que meu objeto não se movimente

```
#Praticar movimentação de objetos
from tkinter import*

class Bola(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.janela = Tk()
        self.janela.geometry('600x500')
        self.janela.title ('Bola')
        self.janela.resizable(False,False)

        self.frame = Frame(bg='blue')
        self.frame.pack()

        self.canvas = Canvas(self.frame, bg='blue', width=400, height=400, cursor='target')
        self.canvas.pack()

        raio = 29
        p = (100,200)
        self.canvas.create_oval(p[0],p[1],p[0]+raio,p[1]+raio, fill='grey' )
        self.vx = self.vy = 3
        self.x, self.y = p

        self.iniciar = Button(self.janela, text='INICIAR', command=self.comecar)
        self.iniciar.pack()
        self.janela.mainloop()

    def comecar(self):
        self.jogar()

    def jogar(self):

        self.update()
        self.janela.after(1, 10)

    def update(self):
        self.canvas.move('bolinha' , self.vx ,self.vy)
        self.x += self.vx
        self.y += self.vy


if __name__ == '__main__':
     Bola()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu código tem três problemas:

- Ele não chama a função jogar repetidamente, porque ela não é passada pro `after`.

  ```
  def jogar(self):

      self.update()
      self.janela.after(1, 10)
  ```

  Deveria ser:

  ```
  def jogar(self):

  self.update()
  self.janela.after(1, self.jogar)
  ```
- `bolinha` tem que ser guardado na instância de `Bola`. Assim,

  ```
  self.canvas.create_oval(p[0],p[1],p[0]+raio,p[1]+raio, fill='grey' )
  ```

  Deveria guardar o objeto como um objeto da classe:

  ```
  self.bolinha = self.canvas.create_oval(p[0], p[1], p[0] + raio, p[1] + raio, fill='grey')
  ```
- A função `move` deve que ser chamada com o objeto a ser movido como primeiro argumento. Assim,

  ```
  self.canvas.move('bolinha' , self.vx ,self.vy)
  ```

  Deve ficar:

  ```
  self.canvas.move(self.bolinha, self.vx ,self.vy)
  ```